# Spring hierarchical context

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, applicationcontext, hierarchical

I have following problem:
I'm trying to implement Spring in existing **ear** application (using Jboss as App Server and Hibernate as ORM).
The ear application consists of **war**(basically few simple servlets), **har**(hibernate archive which has only the data model-as classes and the corresponding hibernate mapping files - as xmls), **sar**(only one parsing class as scheduled task). So, I'm interested how can I share the eventual **appContext** of the har archive in the war (because servlets are retrieving data from the database) and in the sar(because the parser is "filling" the database). On that note, **both** (war and sar) should use the **singleton SessionFactory bean** that would be defined in the har's context. A code example or snippet would be highly appreciated.